# Can all epiphytes be mounted to wood?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, indoors

I just mounted some staghorn ferns and have been reading that *Hoyas* can also be mounted. I recently picked up a lipstick plant, and while I can't find any information on whether this genus (or whatever) can be mounted, I'm wondering if it's a safe assumption that as an epiphyte, mounting would be viable.

Comment: Are you asking about hoyas or lipstick plants?

Comment: lipstick plants. but also I'm wondering if mounting epiphytes might be a safe bet in general.

Comment: Some orchids do well on wood ,others do not seem to;  I think you would need to  research each one. I have some "ground" orchids that I doubt would do well.

Answer (score 2):

So I went ahead and mounted a lipstick plant. It's been almost a week and it seems to be doing alright, with some noticeable growth since mounting. will update in a few months in case anyone's interested

[image: lipstick plant]